# Disabling picture-in-picture through Vimeo Player API

Tags: vimeo-player

Is it possible to disable picture in picture for a video using Vimeo's Player API?

I have set both `pip` and `autopip` to be `false` but these do not disable picture-in-picture.  In Firefox, the firefox pip button is overlaid on the video and in iOS putting the video in full screen mode reveals the pip button.

Support for `disablepictureinpicture` attribute on video elements is good nowadays, but the Vimeo Player does not appear to render this attribute.    Given that the Vimeo Player renders the video player in an `iframe`, you cannot programmatically access the `video` element (due to cross-origin protections).

I've been able to manipulate the `video` element in Firefox and add a `disablepictureinpicture` attribute before the video is played which has the desired effect, but this is more to prove that it could work.

Am I missing an embed option?  Is there an undocumented option?

Here are my embed options at the mo (video id obfuscated) - the videoplayer is linked to a `div`

```
let vimeoOptions = {
    url: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/00000000`,
    controls: true, 
    keyboard: false, 
    title: false,
    autopip: false, 
    pip: false 
}

vimeoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player("myelement", vimeoOptions)
```

Comment: Just to add, in iOS `disablepictureinpicture` appears to be added to the video element, but iOS is ignoring it in this case.   In Firefox, `disablepictureinpicture` is definitely not added to the video element (and yet manually adding it gives the desired result)